# should I always import database.sql to phpmyadmin to connect with java

Tags: java, jdbc, phpmyadmin, workbench

1. I create database using Workbench
2. Export database.mwb to database.sql
3. Import database.sql in PHPMyAdmin
4. Connect with Java

Question: is the 3rd step necessary?

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
java.sql.Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database", "root", "pass");
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make sens at all to me. What has PHP MyAdmin to do with anything? You create a MySQL database and connect to that; end of story.

Comment: What does `database.sql` contains?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that what you've described is a rather roundabout way of initially setting up your database.

You're creating a database structure in MySQL Workbench, then exporting it as an SQL file, then importing it through phpMyAdmin in order to create the database structure. What you can instead do is create the structure directly through MySQL Workbench (or phpMyAdmin; both can do it), which will skip the steps of needing to export and reimport the SQL. Rather than using the two tools, each for a small part of your workflow, you could use one tool for both parts of the process and eliminate a lot of the extra steps.

Note that this assumes you've got the proper access; if your phpMyAdmin is on a hosted environment where you can't connect from MySQL Workbench, then you obviously won't be able to connect from Workbench to create the structure, in which case you can create it from phpMyAdmin directly on your hosted server.

But ultimately, you're only doing this when you first create the application, right? You shouldn't need to recreate your database structure....well, more than once, ideally, though if you upgrade your schema due to changing your application, then I suppose you'd do it more than once, but still not very often.

Anyway, the only reason you'd have to continue to follow this workflow is if you force yourself to use Workbench and can't get Workbench to connect to your remote MySQL server. Otherwise, there are more efficient ways to connect.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I was just a beginner :p 
I've never created the data base, I've just created the schema.
Thank you!